# What is the difference between 'ata_generic.ko' and 'ahci.ko' modules?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I just use clonezilla to keep linux images and partitions. I just simply save an image from old machine and restore a partition in a new machine.

Then I fix grub and initrd image boot script root device searches by UUID. But the disk doesn't seems to exist on the new machine. There is nothing on /dev/disk/by-id/ directory and UUID is not listed.

And then I checked loaded modules, initrd does have a ata module /lib/moudles/3.0.76-0.11-default/kernel/driers/ata/ahci.ko , and it's description is AHCI SATA low level driver and author is 'Jeff Garzik'.

Then I have installed SUSE11SP3 to a new partition with DVDs and it boots correctly and it's initrd does have different module from different author with different description.
/lib/modules/3.0.76-0.11-default/kernel/drivers/ata/aga_generic.ko and it's author is 'Alan Cox'.

What are the difference between these two modules? Is that SUSE install program [anaconda if I'm right ] does assemble modules into the initrd file dynamically at the installation time?

Why there are two different names for ATA driver for same kernel version ?
I know I could replace the files and fix this mess, but what I want to know is why this is happening? How to find out if this supports ATA2 from module name or it's headers ?

Comment: The Kernel Module Explorer, e.g. v3.1 http://modules.libres.ch/browse/linux/v3.1/ ... `ata_generic.ko` : low-level driver for generic ATA http://modules.libres.ch/browse/linux/v3.1/i386/ata_generic/ ... `ahci.ko` : AHCI SATA low-level driver http://modules.libres.ch/browse/linux/v3.1/i386/ahci/

Comment: @KnudLarsen The KME is great. Unfortunately there seems to be no Linux 4.x support yet. I'm sure many of this huge amount of modules were gradually phased out in Linux > 3.5.